# I need help how to add linkstyles class from css to links on the page

Tags: javascript, css, function

I am working with buttons. I have to have a working function that will add the .linkStyles class from my css to all links on the page. The goal of the function is to have the button stylize all the links when clicked. I would appreciate the help!!

```
var changeLinks = function () {
  document.getElementsByTagName("li").classList.toggle("linkStyles");
}

$("li").onclick = changeLinks;
```

This is the html portion:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>FAQ</li>
</ul>

<section id="section2">
  <button type="button" id="links">Links Button</button>
</section>
```

And this is the css portion

```
.linkStyles{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try update your Javascipt with the below code

```js
$('#links').click(function(){
        $("li").toggleClass("linkStyles");
  });
```

```css
.linkStyles{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>FAQ</li>
</ul> 

<section id="section2">
  <button type="button" id="links">Links Button</button>
</section>
```